# Fabric getPointer method not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, openseadragon

I have an `Openseadragon` canvas with `Fabricjs` overlay. I am adding a rectangle wherever user clicks on canvas. It works fine in MS Edge and Google Chrome but in Firefox it gives `event is undefined` error.
Here is the plunker: 
[FabricJs Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/r2xqpxJ5GupGulD691fp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `options.originalEvent` instead of `options.e` in

`var rectLocation = overlay.fabricCanvas().getPointer(options.originalEvent);`

[canvas-click doc](https://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.Viewer.html#.event:canvas-click)

Here is updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u9Njg5ysrNnaLeLMokeg?p=preview).